# Android - Can't get ListPreference value

Tags: android, listpreference

I am trying to get the ListPreference value with this code :

```
public String getEncryption(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    final String encryption = prefs.getString("listPref", "");
    return encryption;
}
```

My ListPreference  is:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/EncryptionCat" >

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="AES"
        android:entries="@array/listArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/listArray2"
        android:key="listPref"
        android:title="@string/SelectEncryption" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

But I am getting an empty string. Why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: What values are in your list preference entryValues? Which value did you select?

Comment: Two values, AES and Base64. Only if I have into prefs.getString("listPref","AES") the app choose the default value, AES, otherwise nothing...